# USB Wireless is not detected when installing 12.04

Tags: wireless, usb, dell, inspiron

When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron E1505, the USB is not detected. During installation, the system asked if I wanted to connect to wireless USB "Real Tec" but not my network. I believe the "Real Tec" to be the USB. This is a new USB which I purchased from Think Penguin.

Now that the install is complete, wireless networking is not an option on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you probably disabled the wireless using a hardware switch. There are certain keys like <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> which may do this.

There is also possibly of an on/off switch. However, most likely the switch is defective and you have permanently disabled the wireless (including USB).